# Knowledge of $\frac{\partial \log(\mu(x))}{\partial x}$ implies knowledge of $\frac{\partial \mu(x)}{\partial x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider a function $\mu: \mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow (0,1]$, where $\mathbb{R}^+$ denotes the set of real numbers $\geq 0$.

Suppose that the derivative
$$
\frac{\partial \log(\mu(x))}{\partial x}
$$
is **known** at each $x\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Does this imply that also
$$
\frac{\partial \mu(x)}{\partial x}
$$
is **known** at each $x\in \mathbb{R}^+$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {\partial \log( \mu (x))} {\partial x}=\frac 1 {\mu (x)} \frac {\partial  \mu (x))} {\partial x}$ so $\frac {\partial  \mu (x))} {\partial x}=\mu (x) \frac {\partial \log( \mu (x))} {\partial x}$. So if $\mu$ is an unknown function for which you only know $\frac {\partial \log( \mu (x))} {\partial x}$ then  you cannot determine $\frac {\partial  \mu (x))} {\partial x}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know at least one value of $\mu$, no; any solution is closed under multiplication of $\mu$ by a constant, i.e. addition of a constant to $\ln\mu$. If you do, yes: let $y:=\ln\mu$ so $\mu:=\exp y,\,\mu^\prime=y^\prime\exp y$ (we obtain $y$ by integrating the known $y^\prime$).